# Authenticate using Devise and Rails Admin for particular routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I use Rails Admin and Devise for admin and user model. I have added one column "admin" to the user model to indicate its identity.

In the `config/routes.rb`, I mount `/admin` for `RailsAdmin:Engine`

I want to only allow `current_user.admin` users to access `/admin`, otherwise, redirect user to home page.

How can I implement this in the cleanest code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

on your admin controllers:

```
class MyAdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :require_admin
end
```

on your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  def require_admin
    unless current_user && current_user.role == 'admin'
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
      redirect_to root_path
    end        
  end
end
```

---

Sorry, didn't notice it was with rails admin, you can do:

```
# in config/initializer/rails_admin.rb

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.try(:admin?)
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I overwrite the default Rails_admin engine? There is no admincontroller that I can subclass.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancancan#handle-unauthorized-access) redirection should be  redirect_to main_app.root_path