# Pundit with Rails plus User, Admin and Roles Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

Following on from [Rails_admin: Should I have admin_user or user with admin role to manage users and admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102718/rails-admin-should-i-have-admin-user-or-user-with-admin-role-to-manage-users-an) I'm wanting to adopt [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/) for its policy elegance for an application. The application has both a User model and an Admin model - one for customers, the other for staff. It is also multi-tenanted, though that should not impact the problem terribly.

I'd also like to have a separate Role model, allowing customers to mix-and-match their own "title" for a Role as they need. This again shouldn't be terribly difficult in implementation.

The hard part is the support for the Pundit Policies to support two different user models - the User (Customer) and Admin (Staff).

Is it a case that I should be using the pundit_user method to set either the Admin or User as the pundit_user (based on the availability of these through current_user and current_admin_user) or is there another method. I haven't found much good documentation on this use case (other than the [short line on github](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user)).

```
def pundit_user
  if !current_admin_user.nil?
    current_admin_user
  elsif !current_user.nil?
    current_user
  else
    nil
  end        
end
```

Comment: Having 2 models when it should clearly be a single one with different roles is what is making this more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @tirdadc the separation I get from the different models is far preferable. Understand where you're coming from, but maintaining distinct models is the approach I want to use to achieve the goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the publicly accesible part of my application, the User model is used. The default Pundit configuration works since `pundit_user` returns `current_user`.

In the admin part of my application, the Administrator model is used. One reason for this is that an admin can stay logged in while impersonating a user (to see what they see in their profile and help troubleshoot).

In admin controllers `pundit_user` returns `current_administrator`.

In Rails Admin, the current user is set to the current administrator:

```
config.authenticate_with do
  warden.authenticate! :scope => :administrator
end
config.current_user_method(&:current_administrator)
```

While I don't use authorization in Rails Admin(all admins have all powers), you should be able to use the `rails_admin_pundit` gem since it does

`@controller.class.send(:alias_method, :pundit_user, :_current_user)`

which is defined in Rails Admin as

```
def _current_user
  instance_eval(&RailsAdmin::Config.current_user_method)
end
```